# How I can perform transpose operation in MySQL table data and columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

For instance, I have a table named 'stdinfo' like

```
Id   Name    Mark
-----------------
1    Helal   10
2    Shakil  15
...  ...     ...
...  ...     ...
...  ...     ...
```

now I want transform the table result like below

```
Name  Helal Shakil ...
----------------------
Id    1     2      ...
Mark  10    15     ...
```

There is one important thing is that the number of rows is not fixed.

Comment: why would you want to do this? Maybe it is another simple way of solving your problem

Comment: you can easily do it on application layer. doing this in sql layer will most probably requires table manipulation. and that is not a good way to code.

Comment: Do you want do this in your mysql table or in your application ?

Comment: i want sql query to get this result

Comment: mysql_query("select * from stdinfo",$connection);

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Table

```
--------------------------------------------------
subject_id    subjectname   classid  teacher_id
---------------------------------------------------
3           Math         3          T-1
4         Economics      4          T-1
5          Physcis       3          T-1
--------------------------------------------------
```

Query:

```
SELECT  sum( if( subjectname = 'Math', subject_id, 0 ) ) AS 'Economics',  
sum( if( subjectname = 'Economics', subject_id, 0 ) ) AS 'Math', 
sum( if( subjectname = 'Physcis', subject_id, 0 ) ) AS 'Physcis' 
FROM tbsubject group by subjectname
```

Output:

```
----------------------------
Math   Economics  Physcis
---------------------------
0   4       0
3   0       0
0   0       5
----------------------------
```

Or you can create a view by programming.more example see pivot table
http://www.krishnasunuwar.com.np/2011/02/crosstab-query-pivot-table-or-transformation-of-rows-into-columns/

Comment: Thanks for your reply...But how we can apply this process when number of subject will be unknown...any idea?

Comment: you can use function or procedure.